# iOS: KinesisEventRecorder without connection

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services

Hi I am working with `AWS Mobile SDK` for iOS.
I am tracking some data with `KinesisEventRecorder`.
When the device has not connection I get this error:

```
AWSiOSSDK v2.4.2 [Error] AWSURLSessionManager.m line:211 | -[AWSURLSessionManager URLSession:task:didCompleteWithError:] | Session task failed with error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1009 "The Internet connection appears to be offline.
```

I know that this framework continue to keep data also without connection, but when the connection come back it seems send nothing. 
Is there some properties to setting?

Comment: The SDK keeps the data and the data will be sent later. How do you tell it sends nothing when connection comes back?

Comment: yes, I read the same in the doc... but I don't see logs keeping my device offline. I saw that log only one time and no anymore. I have doubts about that there is some option to set.